# Per-method routes on flask-restful

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I'm building a RESTful API using `flask-restful` and have run into a small issue.

Essentially, I need to ensure that certain methods only work if a required parameter is provided, while certain others work only if a parameter is *not* provided.

For instance:

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask.ext import restful

api = restful.Api()
class TestResource(restful.Resource):
    def get(self, some_id=None):
        '''GET takes an optional parameter'''
        if some_id:
            return jsonify(something1)
        else:
            return jsonify(something2)

    def post(self):
        '''POST doesn't take any params'''
        #do stuff
        return jsonify(something3)

    def put(self, some_id):
        '''PUT has a mandatory argument'''
        #do stuff
        return jsonify(something4)

restful.add_resource(TestResource, '/testresource/', '/testresource/<string:some_id>')
```

Now, `requests.get('http://mydomain.tld/testresource')` and `requests.get('http://mydomain.tld/testresource/1')` will both work fine, but `requests.post('http://mydomain.tld/testresource/1')` will cause a Python error (`TypeError: post() takes only 1 argument (2 given)`), which causes `flask-restful` to return a `HTTP 500` response.

While I can have an optional parameter for all methods and handle this inside each one, this seems like such a common use-case that it seems likely that `flask-restful` already has a solution built-in for this.

How do I handle per-method routes using `flask-restful`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have tackled this in the past is create 2 resources:

```
api.add_resource(TestResrouces, '/testresource/')
api.add_resource(TestResource, '/testresource/<string: some_id>')
```

you will then need to create 2 classes. Then put your get/post/put code into functions etc...

```
class TestResrouces(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        response = some_function()
        jsonify(something1=response)

class TestResrouces(restful.Resrouce):
    def get(self, some_id):
        some_function(some_id)
        jsonify(something1=response
```